# Is there any way to include formatting in the sphinx_toolbox.collapse extension's collapse block?

Tags: python-sphinx

This question is about https://sphinx-toolbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/collapse.html.

I need to make individual words bold or italic. I've tried surrounding the text with asterisks, but they aren't processed. I've tried creating custom roles such as :bold: and :italic:, but they aren't processed either. Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: Specifically, I have tried both this:

```
.. collapse:: **id**: *String*
```

And this:

```
.. role:: bold
   :class: bold

.. role:: italic
   :class: italic

.. collapse:: :bold:`id` :italic:`String`
```

In both cases, the text of the collapse string was output entirely literally, asterisks and fancy-quotes and all.

Comment: It appears that the label provided to `collapse` may be only a string and renders unformatted. If you wish to alter its formatting universally, you can create a custom style for it. However, if you are trying to format content, not the label of the content, then the content must go on a separate line after a blank line.